# IOS - Remote Video Stream is stop after screen is lock in PJSIP

Tags: ios, swift, stream, pjsip

how to restart video stream when app in foreground?

```
var ci = pjsua_call_info();
     pjsua_call_get_info(incomingCallID, &ci);
     let op =  pjsua_call_vid_strm_op(PJSUA_CALL_VID_STRM_START_TRANSMIT.rawValue)
     var param =  pjsua_call_vid_strm_op_param()
     pjsua_call_vid_strm_op_param_default(&param)
     let success =  pjsua_call_set_vid_strm(ci.id, op, &param)
     if success == PJ_SUCCESS.rawValue {
         print("Start to Stream")
     }
```